# How to add custom variable for user response in survey monkey

Tags: survey, surveymonkey

is there add the username and role of a user responding to a 'survey monkey' survey on my website?

a link and some description would do ,
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending out a Weblink collector, you can set [custom variables](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/What-are-custom-variables-and-how-do-I-use-them) (url query paramaters) to the survey to attach any metadata.

If you are sending out an Email collector, you can set [custom values](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Custom-Data) on a contact as well as regular contact information.

In both cases those will be available on the response. These are all also available in the [public API](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys) if you are building an application.